# Hello i need to get the fastest response, all successful (which means ignore the rejected) and three first responded

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

I've already tried to get the fastest response but in chrome toolbar network i see all the responses but not the fastest. Also as i mentioned above I want to get all the successful responses and ignore rejected

```
const url = 'https://mate-academy.github.io/phone-catalogue-static/api/phones.json';
const detailsUrl = 'https://mate-academy.github.io/phone-catalogue-static/api/phones/';

const getPhones = () => {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('It was an accident'));
        }, 5000);
      }

      return response.json();
    });
};

const getFirstPhoneDetails = (arrId) => {
  return Promise.race(arrId.map(id =>
    fetch(`${detailsUrl}${id}.json`)));
};

getPhones()
  .then(phones => {
    const ids = phones.map(p => p.id);

    return getFirstPhoneDetails(ids);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.warn(error);
  });
```

Comment: `but in chrome toolbar network i see all the responses` I don't understand what you mean with that. The networking tools show how long a request took, and in the timeline, you also see when those started and when they finished.

Comment: @t.niese i'm sorry bcs I'm obviously new to coding. So you wanna say that my code is working for getting the fastest response?

Comment: `Promise.race()` only returns the first one, there's no built-in way to get just the first 3.

Comment: `but not the fastest` how are you determining what's the fastest?

Comment: @user1599011 first to respond i believe